# Loading assembly at runtime with native dependencies (and other files/folders)

Tags: c#, runtime, unmanaged, assembly-loading

I want to load **Assembly A** at runtime. This **Assembly A** exists in a subfolder of the application and has runtime dependencies to some other native assemblies, some jar files and jre folder (so we're talking about some java wrapper). All of these dependencies exist in the same folder as **Assembly A**.
The diagram would be something like this:
[image]

The problem is:
Since **Assembly A** runtime dependencies don't exist in the application (consumer) build folder, I get an exception and I'm not able to use it.

Here's an example of the source code for loading the assembly at runtime and the usage of a type instance owned by that assembly. The exception occurs when I invoke `_ = instance.GetSomething()`. The exception is:

System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'AssemblyA_Dependency.Type' threw an exception.'

```
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"Releases\VersionA\AssemblyA.dll");

        var sdkProxyType = assembly
            .GetExportedTypes()
            .Where(type => typeof(ISdkProxy).IsAssignableFrom(type))
            .First();

        var instance = (ISdkProxy)Activator.CreateInstance(sdkProxyType);

        _ = instance.GetSomething();
```

PS: Keep in mind that if I copy all **Assembly A** dependencies to the consumer build folder it will work just fine.

Is there any way to overcome this issue?

Comment: what exception? how do you load this data? show some code!

Comment: Thanks @sommmen. I've edited the question with your requests.

Comment: check the innerexception of that exception you're getting

Comment: Also, offtopic,  when dealing with dlls and loading i recommend this tool: https://github.com/awaescher/Fusion which displays the fusion log (the thing that resolves dll dependencies) in a nice manner

Comment: The InnerException is somehow obvious. It's a NullReferenceException, resulting by the fact that an instance of the sdkProxyType cannot be created, since the expected runtime dependencies are not in "the right place".